# NDC.remove() Vs. NDC.clear() which is preferred for Multi-threaded Applications?

Tags: java, logging

What is the preferred way to clear the `org.apache.log4j.NDC` when a servlet thread finished execution?

```
NDC.clear()
```

or

```
NDC.remove()
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the two methods seems quite clear, so I think the answer is that it depends on what you're doing:

[`NDC.clear()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html#clear()) - empties the context but leaves the object around for re-use if the thread is likely to be used for something different:

> Clear any nested diagnostic information if any. This method is useful in cases where the same thread can be potentially used over and over in different unrelated contexts.

[`NDC.remove()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html#remove()) - removes the context altogether, to allow its memory to be reclaimed.

> Remove the diagnostic context for this thread.
>
> Each thread that created a diagnostic context by calling push(java.lang.String) should call this method before exiting. Otherwise, the memory used by the thread cannot be reclaimed by the VM.